# How can I search a dictionary for a nltk stem?

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk, stem

I'm having an issue checking to see if a stemmed word exists in a dictionary.  This is for some sentiment analysis work that I am doing.  All I am getting back is this error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sentiment.py", line 369, in <module>
score += int(senti_word_dict.get(get_stem(word)))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is my code for the method to look for a stemmed word through NLTK:

```
def get_stem(word):
    st = SnowballStemmer("english")
    stemmed_word = st.stem(word)
    return '' if stemmed_word is None else stemmed_word
```

Here is the code for checking for that word against the dictionary:

```
for comment in all_comments:
    score = 0
    tokens = tokenize(comment)
    for word in tokens:
      if word in senti_word_dict:
        score += int(senti_word_dict.get(get_stem(word)))
    print(str(score)+" "+comment)
    print('\n')
```

For now I am just getting the score.  Is there a way that I can pass that stemmed word as a string to see what the score is in the dictionary?  If there is anything I am doing wrong or could do better let me know! Thanks!

Comment: `stem_word` is never `None`, because that's the name of your function. You must use `stemmed_word`. Lesson: do not use similar identifiers.

Comment: crap thanks for that.  Still throws the same error.

Comment: Please update your code, because you essentially get a different question now.

Comment: As mentioned before.  I am still getting the same error.  I will update the post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if `word` is in `senti_word_dict`. Perhaps it is. But then you stem it (it becomes a different word!) and attempt to retrieve the stem from the dictionary with `senti_word_dict.get`. If the stem is not in the dictionary (why should it be?), `get()` returns a `None`. Thus, the error. Solution: first stem the word and only then look it up.

Comment: Ah beautiful!  Works now.  Guess I needed a second set of eyes to see my dumb mistake.  Thanks for the input!  Late night coding probably isn't best for me haha.